# SAPUI5 How to display only the first element of an expanded entitySet in table

Tags: sapui5

I am currently using an entityset(i.e, "SolutioningVersions") in my smarttable which i have expanded in controler using

```
    var mBindingParams = oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams");
        mBindingParams.parameters["expand"] = "TEAMID/TEAMDETAILS,SOLREQ,SOLESTIMATE";
```

I have bound it in my table using

```
<VBox items="{ path: 'SOLESTIMATE', templateShareable:false }">
    <Text text="{WBSVARIANT}"/>
</VBox>
```

But "SOLESTIMATE" is having array of objects & i want to show only "WBSVARIANT" from it 1st object in array.
Currently it shows me like this in single cell of table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKkCI.png)

I want to show only 1st element of this array. Also, i dont want to filter array here as objects are not unique.

Answer (score 0):

A formatter can help you:

```
 <Text text="{path: 'WBSVARIANT', formatter: '.formatText'}"/>
```

```
function formatText(items){
   return items[0];
}
```